# how to control the Sound Through Speaker And Earphone in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, speaker

i,m use this hmssdk_flutter package ,

How can I toggle speaker? I mean switch between earphone (built-in earphone) and  speaker.

this hmssdk_flutter ,  Does not support switch in the ios , Only Android

Is there a package, or a way to help me ot switch  ?